# Do not select specific items in IQueryable

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding IQueryable.

how can I remove/don't selct an item in IQueryable.

My code returns an IQueryable with a list of entities like these.

```
{
"ResourceId": "FirstName",
"LanguageId": "ENG",
"Client": NULL,
"ResourceText": "first name x"
}
{
"ResourceId": "FirstName",
"LanguageId": "ENG",
"Client": 1,
"ResourceText": "first name y"
}
{
"ResourceId": "LastName",
"LanguageId": "ENG",
"Client": NULL,
"ResourceText": "last name"
}
{
"ResourceId": "BirthDate"
"LanguageId": "ENG"
"Client": NULL
"ResourceText": "date of birth"
}
```

If there exists an entity with a specific client (not null) for the same ResourceId I want to remove the entity with the client == null

For the above example the result should be

```
{
"ResourceId": "FirstName",
"LanguageId": "ENG",
"Client": 1,
"ResourceText": "first name y"
}
{
"ResourceId": "LastName",
"LanguageId": "ENG",
"Client": NULL,
"ResourceText": "last name"
}
{
"ResourceId": "BirthDate"
"LanguageId": "ENG"
"Client": NULL
"ResourceText": "date of birth"
}
```

thx for your help

Comment: the question is not clear enough, do you mean you have this in an in-memory list, and you want to do a linq query over it?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = clients.Where(c => c.Client == null);
```

Where `clients` is the `IQueryable` entities

Answer (score 0):

I would do this that way:

we have list of clients `clients`. First we want to get all `ResourceID`'s where `Client` is not null:

```
var notNullClients = from c in clients where c.Client != null
                     select c.ResourceID;
```

Then you just filter your set of clints with `where` clause like below:

```
var Clients = from c in clients
              where ( (c.Client == null & !notNullClients.Contains(c.ResourceID)) |
                     (c.Client != null & notNullClients.Contains(c.ResourceID)) )
              select c;
```

First, we want to take clients with `Client` field equal to `null` only if there's no such `ResourceID`, for which we have `Client` not null. Then we take the rest "not null clients".